# Logging distinct array

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log

I am trying to get just one distinct array populated under 'console.log(partial)', eg if the target = 5 and I have a set of numbers [1,1,1,1,1,2,2], the subset will give me just these 2 arrays: [1,1,1,2] or [1,2,2]. However, in my console log, the same 2 sets of arrays are populated multiple times. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
function subsetSum(numbers, target, partial) {
  var s, n, remaining;

  partial = partial || [];

  // sum partial
  s = partial.reduce(function (a, b){
    return a + b;
  }, 0);

  // check if the partial sum is equals to target
 if (s === target) {
    console.log("%s=%s", partial.join("+"), target)
    console.log(partial)
    for(j = 0; j < partial.length; j++){
      if (partial[j] == 1){
      console.log("here")
      }
    }
  }

  if (s >= target) {
    return;  // if we reach the number why bother to continue
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    n = numbers[i];
    remaining = numbers.slice(i + 1);
    subsetSum(remaining, target,       partial.concat([n]));
  }
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get more than one result of

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

because you have more than one element with the same value.

For example, if you number the values and take only the integer value, you can see this happen.

For excluding same results, you need a search in the result set and avoid pusing the same set of numbers.

```js
function subsetSum(numbers, target, partial = []) {
    const
        sum = partial.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b, 10), 0),
        result = [];

    if (sum === target) return [partial];
    if (sum > target) return [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        const n = numbers[i];
        result.push(...subsetSum(numbers.slice(i + 1), target, partial.concat(n)));
    }
    return result;
}

subsetSum(['1#1', '1#2', '1#3', '1#4', '1#5', '2#1', '2#2'], 5).forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```